# Input no asigna valor

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una función en `javascript` que crea una fila en una tabla, en la fila a ingresar tengo una columna de tipo `input` y al asignarle un valor a ese `input` no funciona mas en si cambio el tipo por `label` si se asigna el valor

El código de mi función es el siguiente:

```
        var table = document.getElementById("tabProd");
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        row.addEventListener('click',pressfila,true);
        var columna1=document.createElement("td");
        var celda1 = document.createElement("label");
        var columna2=document.createElement("td");
        var celda2 = document.createElement("label");
        var columna3=document.createElement("td");
        var celda3 = document.createElement("input");
        var columna4=document.createElement("td");
        var celda4 = document.createElement("label");
        var columna5=document.createElement("td");
        var celda5 = document.createElement("label");

        //var celda6 = row.insertCell(5);
        var boton=document.createElement("button");
        boton.textContent="Eliminar";
        //celda6.appendChild(boton);
        celda1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("prod_cod").value;
        celda2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("prod_nom").value;
        celda3.innerHTML = document.getElementById("cant").value;
        celda4.innerHTML = document.getElementById("costoUnitario").value;
        var valunit=document.getElementById("costoUnitario").value*document.getElementById("cant").value;
        valorTotal=valorTotal+valunit;
        var valunitdecimal=valunit.toFixed(2);
        celda5.innerHTML = valunitdecimal.toString();
        columna1.appendChild(celda1);
        columna2.appendChild(celda2);
        columna3.appendChild(celda3);
        columna4.appendChild(celda4);
        columna5.appendChild(celda5);

        row.appendChild(columna1);
        row.appendChild(columna2);
        row.appendChild(columna3);
        row.appendChild(columna4);
        row.appendChild(columna5);

        table.appendChild(row);
```

Answer (score 3):

Para los `input` se usa `value` en lugar de `innerHTML`, quedaría así

```
celda3.value= document.getElementById("cant").value;
```

viendo que celda 3 es tu input

Comment: Gracias me funciono

Answer (score 2):

Es por que a un `input` no le puedes agregar el valor con `innerHTML`, debes usar `value` (el mismo método con el que capturas su valor), por lo cual debes cambiar esto:

```
celda3.innerHTML = document.getElementById("cant").value;
```

Por esto:

```
celda3.value = document.getElementById("cant").value;
```

Comment: gracias Camilo, me funciono